# Close QT Child Window and open again controls are gone

Tags: qt, qml

I’m a newbie, and I’m trying to get a child window to work. I followed after the controls gallery example, and it doesn’t work right, in my opinion. When you click the button to show the child window, it works fine, and if you click the button that says close it does window1.visible = false, which works fine.

However, if instead of clicking the button you close the window using the x box on the window, it destroys the window and if you try to open it again it displays a window, but the controls are missing.

This program initializes the child window before at the beginning of main.qml. It seems to me that if I initialized the window when I actually click the button, that would work, but I can’t figure out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Here's the code sample:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Child Window")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
    Window {
        id: window1

        width: 200
        height: 200

        title: "child window"
        flags: Qt.Dialog

        Rectangle {
            color: syspal.window
            anchors.fill: parent

            Text {
                id: dimensionsText
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: parent.top
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            Text {
                id: availableDimensionsText
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: dimensionsText.bottom
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            Text {
                id: closeText
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: availableDimensionsText.bottom
                text: "Child Window Test"
            }
            Button {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: closeText.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: closeText.bottom
                id: closeWindowButton
                text:"Close"
                width: 98
                tooltip:"Press me, to close this window again"
                onClicked: window1.visible = false
            }
        }
    }


    Button {
        text: qsTr("Open Child Window")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            window1.visible = !window1.visible
        }
    }
}
```

If you click on the button in the child window to close it, it works fine. If you click on the x in the corner to close the window, it closes it but next time you open it the control (close window button and text) are not visible.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I agree with redshark. Please refer to sscce.org for details how to provide a self-contained code.

Comment: OK I added the code sample to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: The code above works fine, both `Win7 x64` and `openSUSE 13.1 x64` with `Qt5.2.0`

Comment: The code works right, what I'm asking is if you close the child window by clicking on the x button in the upper corner of the window, then open the window again the controls are gone. I'm wondering how to program this so that every time I open the window the controls are there, no matter how the user closed it. Can I reinitialize it any way?

Comment: I have more information on this. It works fine on Windows, it doesn't work on my Mac.